# Changing custom input range thumb background-color on disabled input

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have custom input thumb on my range slider and I want it to change color when it is changed to disabled

I tried adding class to thumb like this

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb.disabled
```

and also tried adding disabled directive

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:disabled
```

and none of these works.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#FF6C2C,#FF2626);
  margin-top: -9px;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

I'd like it to be similiar to this:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:disabled {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Is there any option that it can be done? I'm not allowed to user jquery.

Comment: Does it extend a `matInput`?

Comment: It's not extending matInput, sorry I forget to add that I can't use Angular Material as well

Answer (score 1):

Never mind i've finally found solution it should look like this:

```
input[type=range].disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

"disabled" class should be after input[type=range] and then it will work

Answer (score 1):

Write like this and magic started:

```css
input[type="range"]:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
  cursor: context-menu !important;
}

input[type="range"]:disabled::-moz-range-thumb {
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
  cursor: context-menu !important;
}

input[type="range"]:disabled::-ms-thumb {
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
  cursor: context-menu !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#myrange{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline:none;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 overflow:hidden;
}

#myrange::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      border-radius:50%; 
      background:#000000;
      box-shadow: -410px 0 0 400px #007bff;
      cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
 <input style="" type= "range" id="myrange" name="point_count" min= "0"   max = "100" value= "10" disabled >
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.